# Issue with docker Inter container communication on the isolated bridge

Tags: docker

I have created two containers, a sender and a receiver on the the same network. The network i have created is using the following procedure

## docker network create --driver bridge isolated_nw

Each of my containers are run in the above isolated_nw using --net option.

My receiver code has the following 
    int rc = zmq_bind(responder, "tcp://*:16");

And sender has the following line
    int rc = zmq_connect(requester, "tcp://*:16");

Even though they are in the same isolated_nw, they are unable to communicate.

So what am i missing here?